# Determine whether to execute SSIS package inside its Control Flow based on whether an SQL Agent job is currently running

Tags: sql, ssis

How to let an Execute SQL SSIS component decide whether to continue package execution, based on whether a specific SQL Agent job is running.

Comment: The way I handle this is to create a log table in SQL and have jobs create a log entry at start and end.  It's simple to check the log to determine 1) last start time of job, 2) last end time of job and 3) whether a job is currently in progress

Comment: Yes that is essentially the same thing. It's just that I like using direct queries against the [msdb] to get what's going on. But yes, obviously you can create a table and put that information there.

There is lots and lots of ways of doing this. Lots and lots.
Another would be, to have the Agent job you're interested in (the potentially conflicting one) disable by query, the job with our Package in it. and then re-enable it when it's done. That way if our Package was on a say 15 min interval, it won't be able to start while it's disabled.

Comment: Or another way would be to have table Triggers do some logic upon insert into, and from that to determine whether it's ok to proceed or not.

Lots of people use the idea of having their own table in their database, holding information about such things as jobs currently running. Or last execution of certain things. Or last insertions in specific tables.

I just remembered now that I sometimes like using something like
, [timestamp] datetime2 default sysdatetime()
as a last-most field in my tables.
and then the default value constraint will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way of letting the package decide to proceed based on whether a specific SQL Agent job is running at the time the package is invoked.

To do so:

Create an Execute SQL task component at the start of your package.

Give it a query that will ask [msdb] on the execution status of the SQL Agent job you are interested in.
Like so:

```
USE [msdb];

SELECT ISNULL(MAX([sj].[name]),'') AS [JobRunning]
FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobactivity] AS [sja]
INNER JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] AS [sj]
ON [sja].[job_id] = [sj].[job_id]
WHERE [sja].[start_execution_date] IS NOT NULL
      AND [sja].[stop_execution_date] IS NULL
      AND CAST([sja].[start_execution_date] AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
      AND ISNULL([sj].[name],'') LIKE '%NameOfSQLAgentJobThatNeedsToNotBeRunnimg%';
```

And as shown in the screenshot:

[image: adding the SSIS component]

Make sure to set the result set property to single row and to create a Package scoped variable to hold the returned value.

Like so:

[image: adding the appropriate variable]

And then you need to add the fist step of the Package logic whatever that might be and connect the two.

[image]

When you have connected the two, edit the Precedence Constraint and set it to Expression and Constraint and upon Success set the code to:

```
@[User::JobRunning]!="NameOfSQLAgentJobThatNeedsToNotBeRunnimg"
```

like so:

[image]

And that's it.
Save, build, deploy :)